# SIGILL occurs when calling env->ThrowNew() in JNI

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I have been debugging this error for 3 days. In my Android Project, I am trying to throw an exception from Native Code. I have created my Own Exception Class which extends the Standard Java Exception class. Following is the way I throw Exception from Native Code.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_company_MyClass_nativeCall(JNIEnv *env, jclass type)
{
    // Other code stuffs
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/company/MyExceptionClass"); 
    env->ThrowNew(clazz, "Error");
}
```

But when the ThrowNew() is executed, it crashes with following

```
F/libc    (19699): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x7191ed06 (code=1), thread 19699 (mythread.myclass)
I/DEBUG   ( 6189): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 7191ed06
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     r0 00000000  r1 41641d00  r2 4017b394  r3 61ff270f
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     r4 61ff270f  r5 41579870  r6 00000003  r7 bec33238
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     r8 bec33360  r9 6d4fdbf0  sl 41579880  fp bec33374
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     ip 00000000  sp bec331f0  lr 415c02e3  pc 7191ed06  cpsr 600e0030
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d4  6d582ab06d582a78  d5  6d582b206d582ae8
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d6  6d582b906d582b58  d7  3f8000003f800000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d16 6d5396b8416499f8  d17 6d5396b84164a1e8
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d18 6d5041986d539560  d19 6d5396086d5041d0
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d20 6d5042786d504240  d21 6d5394486d5042b0
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d22 6d5395286d539480  d23 6d5395d06d539598
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 6189):     scr 60000010
```

I also tried with env->Throw() with throwable Object. But the behaviour is the same. I thought it could be dynamic libc support issue from the tablet device (Sony Z2) so I used static libc++ compile with Following gradle file. But It didn't have any effect. I still get the crash.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {

            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23", "-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-23", "-DANDROID_PIE=ON", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                cppFlags "-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-23", "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                cFlags "-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-23", "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-23"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters  'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

    }

    publishNonDefault true

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            versionName "0.0.1-internal"
        }
        consumer {
            versionName "0.0.1-public"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you reproduce it with a tiny test app that has only one JNI function (the one that calls `env->ThrowNew()`) ? If no - it is very likely that something other inside your app leads to this crash. Maybe you get memory corruption somewhere or whatever else.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try that..

Comment: I found the problem. It was because of very stupid reasons. First I was having scoped ref on class so somehow it was releasing the reference and the jclass memory. Not sure why ThrowNew didnt keep its own ref. The other reason was I didnt return immediately after Throw.